# Facebook Graph API PHP SDK posting on page as page

Tags: php, api, facebook

It's final try with PHP, if it fails, I'll try with JS. So my goal is to post on FB page as "Page name" through PHP: this is what I want to get

[image: View 1]

But all I get is shown pic below. Also, it's visible ONLY to this profile (not to friends/ppl who like/etc.).

[image: View 2]

This is my current code

```
function post_facebook($data=null, $redir = null){
        $result = "";
        require_once (ROOT. "/apps/configuration/models/ConfigurationItem.php");
        require_once (ROOT . "/components/facebook/facebook.php");

        $this->ConfigurationItem = new ConfigurationItem($this->getContext());

        $row=$this->ConfigurationItem->findByCatKeyItemKey('system','facebook_login');
        $apiid=$row['value']; <= Correct apiid

        $row=$this->ConfigurationItem->findByCatKeyItemKey('system','facebook_pass');
        $secret=$row['value']; <= Correct secret key

        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => $apiid,
          'secret' => $secret,
          'cookie' => true,
        ));

        $session = $facebook->getSession();
        $me = null;
        if ($session) {
            try {
                $uid = $facebook->getUser();
                $me = $facebook->api('/me');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
            }
            $message=$data['facebook_text'];
            $attachment = array(
                'message' => $data['facebook_text'],
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'link' => $this->getLinkToLatestNews(),
                'description' => '',
            );

            try {
                $facebook->api('/PAGE ID/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
                $result = "Facebook: Sent";
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $result = "Facebook: Failed";
                error_log($e);
            }
        } else {
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
            header("Location: ".$login_url);
            exit;
        }

        echo $result;
        exit;
        //return $result;

    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? I couldn't find anything in API documentation/top google results, only for JS. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll need to make sure you're requesting the 'manage_pages' permission for the user. Once you've got that you can do `$facebook->api('/me/accounts')` and you'll receive a token back (along with the page info) that you can use to post on the page *as* the page.

Comment: The key to solve this was getting access token - I missed that part earlier. I owe you!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to be able to post a link with an image (as page as poster)??

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this most of the day, then found that not using setAccessToken(page_access_token) was the only thing preventing it from working for me. I found that in a stackoverflow post from 18 months ago. I'll put my solution here, for anyone who has this question in the future:

```
protected $scope = "email,publish_stream,manage_pages";

    $url = "{$api_url}/{$fbusername}/accounts?access_token=".$access_token;
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    foreach($response->data as $data) {
        try
        {
            $res = $this->SDK->setAccessToken($data->access_token);
            $res = $this->SDK->api(
                "{$data->id}/feed",
                "POST",
                array('link' => 'www.example.com',
                      'message' => 'This is a test message from php',)
            );
            log::debug(__FUNCTION__, print_r($res,true));
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            log::debug(__FUNCTION__, $e->getType().": ".$e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$feed = '/v2.8/' . $pageID . '/' . "feed";
$params = array(
 "access_token" => AQUI TU TOKEN // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
);
$params[ "link" ] = "https://zapatillasnewbalancebaratas.blogspot.com/2018/11/zapatilla-new-balance-ml515-col.html";
$params[ "message" ] = "Zapatilla New Balance Ml515 Col";
$params[ "method" ] = POST;

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com" . $feed;


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $output;
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it