# post a link in facebook graph api explorer as a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-c#-sdk

i am using graph api explorer and an application to post on the wall of a page of my own

when i use the field message and put in  it the link it will be posted as a link string only without the pictures in the link as u post it from outside the graph explorer and the poster will be the name of the page via the application

but when i use the "link" field and put the link in it, it will give the form that i want but the poster will be the name of the account and not the name of the page

1st of all: i am trying the post in the graph api explorer before i use my c# console application that will post to the page wall. if i copy the link of a website page and open the page through facebook and paste the link in the status filed it will automatically generate something like a form that contain the picture and some details and if i click post the status will appear as posted by the page itself and it will contain first the link as a text and then the form that i talked about will appear

if i use the c# sdk and post the status as: fbArgs["message"] = txtT.ToString(); facebook.Post("/PAGE_ID/feed", fbArgs); the post will contain the link only without the form that appears automatically when I post the same string in the facebook page website. if i use the "link" field with the link as a value it will be posted by the name of the account but with the form that i want?

how can i post a link that will generate automatically the form that will be created when u paste a link in the status edit box on the facebook website??

Comment: Can you put the code you are using to publish ?

Comment: You can check how to post as page here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#impersonation

Answer (score 1):

You cal refer to this old stackover flow question: [Facebook Graph API PHP SDK posting on page as page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055440/facebook-graph-api-php-sdk-posting-on-page-as-page)

You have to manually specify the meta tags for the link using the parameters:

`picture`   Post thumbnail image (can only be used if link is specified)

`name`  Post name (can only be used if link is specified)

`caption`   Post caption (can only be used if link is specified)

`description`   Post description (can only be used if link is specified)

> You can create a post on a Page by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   PAGE_ID/feed with the publish_stream and manage_pages permissions and
>   the following parameters. Additionally, Page posts can also be
>   scheduled to go live at a future time up to 6 months or can be created
>   in an "unpublished" state where they are not visible on the pages
>   timeline or in the page fan's news feeds. Unpublished posts can be
>   used as Sponsored Stories.

Read more at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#links

Comment: 1st of all: i am trying the post in the graph api explorer before i use my c# console application that will post to the page wall
if i copy  the link of a website page and open the page through facebook and past the link in the status filed it will automatically generate something like a form that contain the picture and some details and if i click post the status will appear as posted by the page itself and it will contain first the link as a text and then the form that i talked about will appear

Comment: if i use the c# sdk and post the status as:
fbArgs["message"] = txtT.ToString();
facebook.Post("/PAGE_ID/feed", fbArgs); the post will contain the link only without the form that appears automatically when I post the same string in the facebook page website
if i use the "link" field with the link as a value it will be posted by the name of the account but with the form that i want?
so my question is not same as the one you mentioned